# Reload AssemblyInfo.cs after RunTime modification in c# Web app

Tags: c#, web, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I am working on a c# project, where after runtime, I add dependencys into AssemblyInfo.cs using File, based on elements I retrieve from a database.

When i work on local, after the file is modified, Visual studio asks me to reload the file, and then takes the modifications into account. If i don't press yes, the modifications are not used by the program.

Now is there any way to reload that file without user input ? So that when I publish my app to my server, it does get reloaded when I am not able to do it manually.

Thank you in advance,
Gauthier

Comment: Not sure why you need to modify `AssemblyInfo` and not just provide this information dynamically from the app? I'm assuming VS does hot reload the dll's after it recompile `AssemblyInfo.cs` with the new changes. Not sure how you host your app but for example IIS does reload when for example `web.config` is changed. There might be some similar ways but not sure if that's the best approach

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I'm using my company's framework, and need to add to AssemblyInfo a custom attribute thats creates a Runtime dependency to an assembly, that's why.  I can't make these changes in web.config because of the way the framework works :/ The problem is that I have to retrieve the values to put in the custom attribute, only at runtime, so can't just put the attribute into AssemblyInfo from the get-go.